# Why does information need a citation, but an image needs a credit line?

Tags: citations, methodology

I am using some images from the National Archives in my article, and it is my understanding they are in the public domain. I wrote to the National Archives requesting confirmation on usage rights and how to cite, and they don't need a citation, but a credit line, example: "Courtesy National Archives, photo no. 26-G-3422". That means the original author of the photographs, date, and other details don't need to even be included in my article.

An image might contain as much value to readers as writing, or at least support the information given. So why is it that information needs to be cited, but images are instead credited?

Comment: That image  is just a piece of evidence, like an antique brick you investigated in an archive, or an old newspaper article or advertisement you looked up in an archive, or a book of law. The conclusion you draw from it are 100% your own responsibility.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The idea that "information needs a citation and images need a credit line" is incorrect.  The choice of attribution by citation, credit line, or nothing, depends on the type of publication.

Books and news media typically use credit lines for images.  The journals I publish in typically use citations for images.  Some journals also include a "used with permission" statement, which is not like a news media credit line.  The National Archives do not deal with the journals I publish in, but they do deal with news media frequently.  So the National Archives recommends a credit line as that's what they are used to.

I recommend including both the citation and the credit line, unless the journal objects.  Since the image is public domain, only the opinion of the publisher of your article really matters.

Comment: @einpoklum Fair use is judged by courts on a case-by-case basis, and there are no automatic rules like "using an image in a scientific publication is fair use". Use for an educational purpose is one factor in favour of it being considered fair use, but possible factors against it being fair use include: use for commercial purposes (if the journal is not open-access), use in a way which doesn't criticise the image, and use of the entirety of the image as opposed to a smaller part of it.

Comment: @kaya3: I realize from your comment that I used the wrong term. Use for scientific research purposes and use in education are two different things. Also, I just noticed that [here](http://copyrightblog.kluweriplaw.com/2021/11/22/research-exceptions-in-comparative-copyright-law/) it is suggested that legal restrictions of some kind are placed on use in research, so for now I'll just retract my comment.

Comment: @einpoklum Copyright laws do have exceptions for research, but (as far as I know) this generally just means researchers can make copies of protected works for the purpose of doing research (e.g. you're allowed to copy text, images, audio or video in order to run it through some kind of computational analysis); it's not generally true that copies of protected works can be included in research publications without permission. That's how it is in the UK, at least.

Comment: @kaya3: "Doing research" involves the publication of results, which in turns involves the republication of parts of existing work. I'm not familiar with British law, but I very much doubt you need permission to cite from a protected work in a research publication, even if it's a picture rather than some text or numbers. Of course that's not the same as publishing a full copy of the work.

Comment: @einpoklum Where I wrote "doing research", I meant as opposed to the publication of the research. The text of the law would phrase this more specifically, of course.

Comment: @kaya3: I don't see how the publication can be said to not be part of "doing research", but ok.

Answer (score 18):

If we agree that a picture is worth a thousand words, then the situation is not as asymmetric as it appears.  If you were to include, verbatim, a thousand words from another work, you would need permission and a credit line due to copyright.

A credit line does not always mean you do not need make a citation to the source.  In many cases, you will want the caption of the figure to include information that puts the image in context, and so often will need a citation in the caption.  I like to find a way to cite the paper in addition to putting in the credit line.  In my view, the credit line keeps the journal's lawyer's happy, while the citation is for the benefit of the reader and the authors of the other paper.

Comment: +1  the credit line keeps the journal's lawyer's happy, while the citation is for the benefit of the reader and the authors of the other paper

Comment: This does not agree with the question, which specified that the image is in the public domain.